# Admin logout not working with cake php

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have an issue with admin logout in CakePHP. Logout is not working for admin.

My admin logout function is:

```
public function logout()
{ 
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout()); 
}
```

I receive the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdENK.png

Comment: What is your parent controller for the admin prefix controllers(It's app controller or something else)?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Can you confirm that you have created that class in the appropriate directory and namespace?

Comment: Please share your App controller code.